# protobuf-net message serialized size property

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

We are using protobuf-net for serialization and deserialization of messages in an application whose public protocol is based on Google Protocol Buffers. The library is excellent and covers our all requirements except for this one: we need to find out the serialized message length in bytes before the message is actually serialized.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313724/protocol-buffers-c-protobuf-net-messagebytesize) has already been asked a year and a half ago and according to Marc, the only way to do this was to serialize to a MemoryStream and read the `.Length` property afterwards. This is not acceptable in our case, because MemoryStream allocates a byte buffer behind the scenes and we have to avoid this.

This line from the same response gives us hope that it might be possible after all:

> If you clarify what the use-case is, I'm sure we can make it easily
>   available (if it isn't already).

Here is our use case. We have messages whose size varies between several bytes and two megabytes. The application pre-allocates byte buffers used for socket operations and for serializing / deserializing and once the warm-up phase is over, no additional buffers can be created (hint: avoding GC and heap fragmentation). Byte buffers are essentially pooled. We also want to avoid copying bytes between buffers / streams as much as possible.

We have come up with two possible strategies and both of them require message size upfront:

1. Use (large) fixed-size byte buffers and serialize all messages that can fit into one buffer; send the content of the buffer using `Socket.Send`. We have to know when the next message cannot fit into the buffer and stop serializing. Without message size, the only way to achieve this is to wait for an exception to occur during `Serialize`.
2. Use (small) variable size byte buffers and serialize each message into one buffer; send the content of the buffer using `Socket.Send`. In order to check out the byte buffer with appropriate size from the pool, we need to know how much bytes does a serialized message have.

Because the protocol is already defined (we cannot change this) and requires message length prefix to be Varint32, we cannot use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` method.

So is it possible to add a method that estimates a message size without serialization into a stream? If it is something that does not fit into the current feature set and roadmap of the library, but is doable, we are interested into extending the library ourselves. We are also looking for alternative approaches, if there are any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted, this is not immediately available, as the code intentionally tries to do a single pass over the data (especially `IEnumerable<T>` etc). Depending on your data, though, it might *already* be doing a moderate amount of copying, to allow for the fact that sub-messages are *also* length-prefixed, so might need juggling. This juggling can be greatly reduced by using the "grouped" sub-format *internally* in the message, as groups allow forwards-only construction without track-backs.

> So is it possible to add a method that estimates a message size without serialization into a stream?

An estimate is next to useless; since there is no terminator, it needs to be exact. Ultimately, the sizes are a little hard to predict without actually doing it. There was some code in v1 for size prediction, but the single-pass code currently seems preferred, and in most cases the buffer overhead is nominal (there is code in place to re-use the internal buffers so that it doesn't spend all the time allocating buffers for small messages).

If your message *internally* is forwards-only (grouped), then a cheat might be to serialize to a fake stream that *measures*, but drops all the data; you'd end up serializing twice, however.

Re:

> and requires message length prefix to be Varint32, we cannot use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` method

I'm not quite sure I see the relationship there - it allows a range of formats etc to be used here; perhaps if you can be more specific?

Re copying data around - an idea I played with here is that of using sub-normal forms for the length prefix. For example, it might be that in most cases 5 bytes is plenty, so *rather than juggle*, it could leave 5 bytes, and then simply overwrite **without** condensing (since the octet `10000000` still means "zero and continue", even if it is redundant). This would still need to be buffered (to allow backfill), but would not require  and movement of the data.

A final simple idea would be simply: serialize to a `FileStream`; then write the file length, and the file data. It trades memory usage for IO, obviously.

Comment: Regarding length prefix and SerializeWithLengthPrefix: the method can write prefixes encoded as Base128, Fixed32 and Fixed32BigEndian, but it does not support the Varint32 type. Our protocol defines the following message structure: [type:varint32][length:varint32][actual protobuf message].

Comment: @Boris which is exactly what base-128 with a field-number **is**. The field-number would be === the type (probably with a >>3 shift). I'd need to see the *exact bytes*, but that is probably usable. If not, just add the type manually, and encode using base-128 and field 0 (which will skip the field number)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I guess I missed that one. And thank you for the detailed response. We are still evaluating possible approaches and trying to find the optimal way with as little data juggling and buffer allocations as possible.